# A statement in second-order-arithmetic which proves second-order-arithmetic consistency

Tags: incompleteness, second-order-logic

Is there a statement in second order arithmetic which it's truth proves the consistency of second order arithmetic? Note that if such statement exists it must be unprovable in second order arithmetic.

Comment: In the context of second-order logic, you have to be careful what you mean when you say "consistent" since there is no complete sound proof system for second-order logic (at least, with the [standard semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics)) - do you mean *satisfiability*, or consistency *with respect to some fixed incomplete proof system*, or ...? Or are you talking about the *first-order* theory $Z_2$, generally (and unfortunately in my opinion) called "second-order arithmetic"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but let's give it a try:

"There exists a smallest inaccessible cardinal larger than the size of set of sets of all the numbers in question."

Comment: although this statement proves the consistency of second order arithmetic, I think you can't phrase it in second order arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't mention a base theory - we want a sentence that proves the consistency of $Z_2$ relative to which theory?

Depending on the base theory there are several options, including:

- The Gödel sentence of $Z_2$ directly implies the consistency of $Z_2$ over primitive recursive arithmetic.
- The sentence "there is a countable $\omega$-model of ZFC" implies the consistency of $Z_2$ over $\text{ACA}_0$. We could replace ZFC with any theory that proves the consistency of second-order arithmetic. Replacing $\text{ACA}_0$ with a weaker base theory is complicated because weaker theories have trouble handling the satisfaction relation for countable models.

Comment: I think I am talking about the base theory of Peano arithmetic with the axiom of induction.

Comment: @D. Hershko: - in that case, you must be looking for a sentence of Peano arithmetic, rather than second-order arithmetic, so no set quantifiers.   The Gödel sentence will work then. There is a separate issue that "second order arithmetic" is not just Peano arithmetic plus a single induction axiom - that theory is very easy to prove consistent, since it has no set existence axioms. It is essentially the same strength as PA. Actual second-order arithmetic $Z_2$ also includes a set existence axiom scheme and an induction axiom scheme, and has a much higher consistency strength.